# Captcha in Android Application

Tags: android, captcha

I have to implement Captcha in my android app code, but have no idea about how to go about it..

Please can anyone help me out here ??

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/41218856/6295668

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at [SimpleCaptcha](http://simplecaptcha.sourceforge.net/) or [JCaptcha](http://jcaptcha.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: `JCaptcha` sure. I don't know about `SimpleCaptcha` but it should too.

Answer (score 3):

Shameless self promotion, but I HATED all of the other choices, specifically that they are all networked based. Now, I'm sure that mine needs LOTS of work, etc, and is maybe not as secure as using another outside solution, but at least it is easy to use and has a few options.

[Git it here, and have fun changing and committing](https://github.com/floydfix/Android-Easy-Captcha)

Comment: Awesome implementation

Answer (score 2):

Now Google provides SafetyNet reCAPTCHA library for this.
Find more details [here](https://developer.android.com/training/safetynet/recaptcha).

Below are the steps to implement the reCaptcha:

1. Add a SafetyNet API dependency

> ```
> dependencies {
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:15.0.1'
> }
> ```

2. Use API(example from google documentation)

   ```
   public void onClick(View v) {
   SafetyNet.getClient(this).verifyWithRecaptcha(YOUR_API_SITE_KEY)
       .addOnSuccessListener((Executor) this,
           new OnSuccessListener<SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse>() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess(SafetyNetApi.RecaptchaTokenResponse response) {
                   // Indicates communication with reCAPTCHA service was
                   // successful.
                   String userResponseToken = response.getTokenResult();
                   if (!userResponseToken.isEmpty()) {
                       // Validate the user response token using the
                       // reCAPTCHA siteverify API.
                   }
               }
       })
       .addOnFailureListener((Executor) this, new OnFailureListener() {
               @Override
               public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                   if (e instanceof ApiException) {
                       // An error occurred when communicating with the
                       // reCAPTCHA service. Refer to the status code to
                       // handle the error appropriately.
                       ApiException apiException = (ApiException) e;
                       int statusCode = apiException.getStatusCode();
                       Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + CommonStatusCodes
                               .getStatusCodeString(statusCode));
                   } else {
                       // A different, unknown type of error occurred.
                       Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + e.getMessage());
                   }
               }
       });
   ```

   }

Comment: reCAPTCHA is pretty good solution, however, malfunction in mobile devices, such as huawei, without GmsCore.